# Returning value from a Pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a function shown below which I pass it to pthread_create. I have read plenty of posts and implemented them on my code, However I still can not return a value.

```
void *threaded_FFT(void* arg) {
    struct arg_struct *data = (struct arg_struct *)arg;

    data->base = data->fft->in;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        data->base[i].re =  data->input[i]; data->base[i].im =0.0; 
    }

    usleep(1);

    gpu_fft_execute(data->fft);
    data->base = data->fft->out;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        data->output[i]= sqrt(((data->base[i].re)*(data->base[i].re))+((data->base[i].im)*(data->base[i].im))); 
    }

    return (void *)data->output; 
}
```

When I add a printf line to display data->output[0...N], I can clearly see that they've proper values which shows function working properly.

I'm trying this in my main function

```
void *outData;
...
pthread_join(threads[],&outData);
...
printf("%f\n",(float *)outData);
```

This always returns me value of 0.000000

Comment: This: `printf("%f\n",(float *)outData);` is trying to print a pointer as if it were a `float` -> *undefined behavior*. Try a dereference or an index.

Comment: 'return (void *)data->output;' dubious cast...

Comment: "*`struct arg_struct *data = (struct arg_struct *)arg;`*" What is `struct arg_struct` and how had been initialised what was passed to the thread Also no need to cast `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: And couldn't you just use the variable you passed to the thread to print the results? Why take the burden to return anything via `pthread_join()`?

Comment: @alk I have 2 thread working inside of a infinite loop. In my program, I must be sure thread[0] ends and returns a value before thread[1] starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%f\n",(float *)outData);
```

`%f` expects a floating point value, not a pointer.  This might work:

```
printf("%f\n", ((float *)outData)[0]);
```

You have not posted your type definitions, so it is not clear whether `outData` actually points to a `float` value.